# Why can the background page be an html file?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

In `manifest.json`, we specify our background page and can put an `html` or a `js` file for it. Since it is only a script that executes what sense does it make to have an `html` file for it?
I mean where is UI going to get shown anyway?

Similarly the `devtools_page` property has to be an `html` file. What sense does that make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not be shown anywhere (that's the essence of "background"), but some elements on it make sense.

- You can have an `<audio>` tag, and if you play it, it will be heard.
- You can have an `<iframe>` with some other page loaded invisibly.
- ..and so on

<s>As for `devtools_page`, it would actually be visible in the interface (as an extra panel in the DevTools)</s>

It is possible that `devtools_page` must be an HTML file just for legacy reasons: it was not updated when manifest version 2 rolled out with changes to how background pages are specified. Still, the same arguments as above apply.

Comment: `devtools_page` is not what gives the UI to a new panel. It must execute a `chrome.devtools.panels.create...` with the name of the new `html` file to serve as the extra panel's UI.

Comment: I have an extension that must use the background's DOM to insert html so i can copy it to the clipboard. Must be done in background as the permission for clipboard is for background not content

Comment: One must note that even if the background page is defined through scripts, it's still running in a page context, with a full-featured, auto-generated DOM present. So it's possible to add required DOM nodes from the script; it's just easier sometimes to pre-define them.

Answer (score 1):

`background_page` is a legacy feature from the initial support of extensions in Chrome. `background.scripts` was added in [Chrome 18](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new#18). I can't speak for Google's original intentions but I'd guess that in the original design using an page felt more natural and would be less likely to confuse developers. Once they realized how many `background_page`s were just being used to load JavaScript it made sense to explicitly support that.